# Eclipse keeps giving errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to link the Neuroph library to Eclipse using Ubuntu 16.04. I can actually link the libraries, but when I run the program I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory 
      at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.(NeuralNetwork.java:106) 
      at org.neuroph.nnet.Perceptron.(Perceptron.java:55) 
      at testneur.main.main(main.java:14) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory 
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) 
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) 
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) 
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 3 more
```

My code is very simple:

```
NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = new Perceptron(2, 1);
```

When I place the mouse on the Perceptron class I have the following notification:

```
This element neither has neither attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
```

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse helps you?

Comment: Nope, this is what i have been doing..the Javadoc file is missing..i think